# jQuery to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site that I need to write some JS for only I cant user any libraries such as jQuery...

The code I need to rewrite is a simple `if statement`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var totalP = $('#shopping-cart-totals-table tr:first .a-right .price').html();
  totalP = parseFloat(totalP.slice(1));

  if (!window.location.href.indexOf("gpf") > 0) {
    $('ul.sp-methods li:first-of-type').hide();
  } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("gpf") > 0 && totalP < 100){
    $('ul.sp-methods li:last-of-type').hide();
  }

});
```

How would I go about targeting elements such as...

```
var totalP = $('#shopping-cart-totals-table tr:first .a-right .price');
```

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript DOM traversing. document.querySelector might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use method `.querySelectorAll()` either on `document` or DOM element.